# Replacing a built in function with my own one

Tags: replacement, scoping, rule

I'd like to replace a built in Mathematica function with my own function. In the particular case I'd like to have:

```
reprule = {LaguerreL[n, k, r] -> (-1)^i*(n + k)!/((n - i)!*(k + i)!*i!)*r^i};
```

(I'm aware that for the identity to hold, I have to sum over `i` from `0` to `n`, but this is done in an other step)

And this works for

```
LaguerreL[n, k, r] /. reprule
((-1)^i r^i (k + n)!)/(i! (i + k)! (-i + n)!)
```

but not for

```
LaguerreL[a, b, c] /. reprule
LaguerreL[a, b, c]
```

I was doing some research and found that Block, Function or Module could do the trick, but I have no idea how...

Thanks in advance for your help!
If possible please also explain the solution, since I'd like to learn ;)

**EDIT:** As already written in the comments (better late than never): Here's the final solution - maybe someone might find it helpful.

```
moveindex1[ x_] := (x /. LaguerreL[-1, k_, arg_] :>
 (LaguerreL[0, k, arg] - LaguerreL[0, k - 1, arg]));
moveindex2[ x_] := (x /. LaguerreL[-2, k_, arg_] :>
 ((LaguerreL[0, k, arg] - LaguerreL[0, k - 1, arg])
  - (LaguerreL[0, k - 1, arg] - LaguerreL[0, k - 2, arg])));
```

This allows one to use

```
Simplify[func, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, moveindex1, moveindex2}]
```

where `func` can be some Laguerre polynomials where the indices are supposed to be shifted.

Comment: Try with `LaguerreL[n_, k_, r_] :>`, more in [ApplyingTransformationRules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html)

Comment: Tanks a lot! That already did it!
How can I mark this question as answered?

Comment: This is a useful read: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html

Comment: To mark the question as answered it is encouraged to answer the question yourself using the comments giving credit to the comment that helped you.

Comment: Eventually, someone might find the final solution helpful:
`moveindex1[
   x_] := (x /. 
    LaguerreL[-1, k_, 
      arg_] :> (LaguerreL[0, k, arg] - LaguerreL[0, k - 1, arg]));`
`moveindex2[
   x_] := (x /. 
    LaguerreL[-2, k_, 
      arg_] :> ((LaguerreL[0, k, arg] - 
         LaguerreL[0, k - 1, arg]) - (LaguerreL[0, k - 1, arg] - 
         LaguerreL[0, k - 2, arg])));`
This allows one to use `Simplify[func, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, moveindex1, moveindex2}]`, where `func` can be some Laguerre polynomials where the indices are supposed to be shifted.

Comment: @gothicVI, If you have found your solution, I would encourage you to write it out into a formal answer so that it is easier for others to find and understand in the future.

Comment: @kickert I'd do that if the question wasn't closed and thus unable to be answered...